# Can we make functions type dependant (derived from?) on its function types (when called)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Say we have this complex set of functions that:

```js
    interface Succes<a> {
      kind: 'succes'
      value: a
    }
    interface Failure<e> {
      kind: 'failure'
      error: e
    }

    type Result<a, e> = Succes<a> | Failure<e>

    const unit = <a>(a:a): Succes<a> => ({kind: 'succes', value: a})
    const fail = <e>(e:e): Failure<e> => ({kind: 'failure', error: e})

    interface fun<a, b> { (a: a): b }

    const map = <a,b, e>(f: fun<a, b>): fun<Result<a,e>, Result<b,e>> => r => 
      r.kind == 'succes' ? unit(f(r.value)) : r

    const join = <a, e>(r:Result<Result<a, e>, e>): Result<a, e> => 
      r.kind == 'failure' ? r : r.value

    const then = <a, b, e>(f:fun<a, Result<b, e>>) => (r:Result<a, e>) => 
        join(map(f)(r))

    const railRoad = <a, e>(r: Result<a, e>) => ({
      map: <b>(f: (a:a) => b) => railRoad<b, e>(map<a, b, e>(f)(r)),
      then: <b>(f: (a:a) => Result<b,e>) => railRoad(then(f)(r))
    })
```

The highlighted bit is the last `railRoad` bit. 
We can use this like so:

```js
railRoad<User, *somePossibleErrors*>(getUser())
  .then(formatName)
  .map(greet)
```

This has some nice possibilities, it allows us to handle all errors in an arbitrary-length pipeline of functions, but in this - we have to specify the set of errors we have to handle. I'd love for the `e` in `railRoad` to be derived from the `map` function, and then function `e` value.

Is that something we can do? So that as we call functions with `.then` or `.map` their signature gets added to a type in the original function (`railRoad`)?

A TS playground for this code is [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=30&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcFIM4B44B8yA3gFDLIDWoAJgFzIDk2mOj5yAbnADboQM4pAL6lQkWIhQAxOMD5QIuCETIVqIek3jz0i9hWhQA9lAYQRpUmACeABxQAlCCx5h8AGmQrkAXjSsLvhEAD7IsrqKygRWCMYg2GDI6CDASf7BABTYxgC2AnAAlAwYWEGEfkSZxBpazIHYjF7cfALIOfnChaRxCUk6PH7I0dl5AhDF4XIKSj6+VTW0DIwDehBN3lAmZu1jXVbi0PBIyDApnsgARqrIo-mCk5fIoj3xici5cHZDnpdeKpkYAwziALtdJiDcM5XO44B4VF5oeg3Lg-ioiPNkFBKsgOFAAHS1Pz+eplRrIAD8yVSYEBmQJLX4hUKyAYUFibySACtjKAfnDvAR6XQkSjRbD-gRJZNxRc5kQ8YTaMTtNM1oxKVjWVj8YyLK8+sgwAALCAgfleP6CwF0SEC2VW9EszHC2UClTOhUUHmgTKfOyAwr05kcw1QaaOYxwGgW607N3SnHVDj+hiooVA24dAqeq658PySPR1GSv1fMGlmBBqDMjwcE1mtPXG1ZsZ0Io4h3wgj5iNRmiZBsgQPB7r7WI8ODYbDIACq2GgJA4vUSUEwYFMmTs6EuPGACFOwCgiRAcHu7TAUFAAHMvNvd-vkJOT2e2qubyziKIXiukteIGA86Lv4mQyi4yLuEBUBeIwIDGAAtOgC5QIwGJEAMmSwQhSHQIw3QGu8MCmJ8YAAHKvkMmToAwUFgTCuDviAt5MHB8GnvkqE4moyDADAtzoPiMBHi++TIAAZGJyT4s+YDsRMWIAXo5opGkmQAAYACTEAJQnHrJr7CMgWkCTJcnCGp3QULxVGCcJ+n5CyihgEp1KqTpdlyZZPEwDZpmvo5ilQMpNK+VO9kTHigXmhhWFsa+eGWL+yDXooAGUXJDCMdeuZqaaPA8MYRnEGZalWAWPBFjQuBQTBrFyRqYSxThKHIAA9AAVI1rEQAAHsAiRwOAjDta1Qr-oByGgV5+JDoCxFwGR-kcPi-qZClEAAd0QA)

Comment: It took me a couple of readings but I see what you mean now. When we call `railRoad(getUser())` (no generic arguments), then `e` is implicitly assumed to be `"no-user"` which then breaks on `then` since it will produce `e = "no-name"` and it doesn't match the type signature where `e = "no-user"`. Explicitly setting the generic arguments as `railRoad<User, 'no-name' | 'no-user'>(getUser())` works and prevents the compilation error...but it might be cumbersome in a larger chain. Interesting question, even though I don't have the answer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows I'll be using the TS type parameter naming conventions (captial letters) and I've changed "succes" to "success" everywhere.  These are cosmetic changes you can ignore if you want.   I've kept the convention of referring to the "success" types as `A` and `B`, and I will refer to the "failure" types as `E` and `F`.  I admit `F` isn't a great name for an error type but the alphabetic parallel to `A`/`B` was too enticing for me to resist.

---

The primary issue is probably that your `then()` function and your `railRoad()` function doesn't have a concept of expanding the error type.  Here's one way of doing it with `then()`:

```
const then = <A, B, F>(f: fun<A, Result<B, F>>) => <E>(r: Result<A, E>) =>
  join(map<A, Result<B, E | F>, E>(f)(r))
```

Here the initial function takes something that turns an `A` into a `Result<B, F>`, and then it takes a `Result<A, E>`, and produces a `Result<B, E | F>`.  This union of `E` and `F` into `E | F` is the key ingredient in getting your inferences to work later.

---

A secondary issue is that your `railRoad()` function uses the [higher order generic type inference support](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions) added in TypeScript 3.4, but the particular formulation leads to quite poor compiler performance.  The inferred type o the function is a recursive type like `{map: () => {map: () => ....`.  To prevent that I created an interface `RailRoaded<A, E>` to represent the return type of `railRoad()`:

```
interface RailRoaded<A, E> {
  map<B>(f: (some: A) => B): RailRoaded<B, E>;
  then<B, F>(f: (some: A) => Result<B, F>): RailRoaded<B, E | F>;
}

const railRoad = <A, E>(r: Result<A, E>): RailRoaded<A, E> => ({
  map: <B>(f: (some: A) => B) => railRoad<B, E>(map<A, B, E>(f)(r)),
  then: <B, F>(f: (some: A) => Result<B, F>) => railRoad(then(f)(r))
})
```

Annotating the return type of `railRoad` as `RailRoaded<A, E>` improves performance dramatically, because the compiler only has to *verify* that the function is compatible and doesn't try to synthesize a new return type for it.  Anyway you can also see how the `then()` method of a `RailRoaded<A, E>` produces a union-typed failure type.

---

That's pretty much it.  Here's what happens when you call it:

```
const chooChoo = railRoad(getUser()).then(formatName).map(greet);
// const chooChoo: RailRoaded<string, "no-user" | "no-name">
```

Looks good, I think.  Just to be sure, let's break that apart to see the inferences for each step:

```
const engine = railRoad(getUser());
// const engine: RailRoaded<User, "no-user">
const car = engine.then(formatName);
// const car: RailRoaded<string, "no-user" | "no-name">
const caboose = car.map(greet);
// const caboose: RailRoaded<string, "no-user" | "no-name">
```

Also good.  All right, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcFIM7YDwCCAfMgN4BQyyA1qACYBcyA5Npjts5cgG5wA26CEwLkAvuVCRYiFADE4wQVAh4AoiQpVaIRi3hL0KrlWhQA9lCZrx5cmACeABxQAlCG35hCAGmQbkAF40dg98YmQAH2QFQxV1IjsEcxBsMGR0EGB04MIiAApscwBbYWQCAEomDCwwvKCSfNIaeiZWUNxmPz5BMqLS5DEK8mTU9IN+IOQEwpKytSqYxWVVAMDG5p09ZgmjCC7kM0smfpQhuyloeCRkGEzfZAAhTWRZ0pFFx8GklLTkYrgTimD0efg0+RgTDuIBBREW0Lw7k83gIYKIfiR6C8eFB-iIJHWyCgDW4UAAdFsgsF2rVOsgAPwZLJgCH5ck9IQVCrIJhQH5jZAAK3MoGBqLxbKYmOx0pRaLRi1lDzWiSo5MpgWpu2MDKJPKJZI5EH5fzAAAsICAxX5cXICpDbvdxUrbfjuYSZlZkErxRp3aqhSKQPkAU4Hi6wVEYuiJTAKmyuRdwFdZN7lq5zHA6BA6MrNNxQzj7Uw3mVKg0nor05ns7ncRoANzcc2WnF+O0QkunD4ViPRqtKDNZnNt-xRu1NiTIEa-dJQatZ60Sr0+hVShe1vMVpoFwFMIud17d8r+ysV+eDmuj8GF8X1+3xqBcnzNi0gfeuw+lnuEvt208XvwQ50PkLbBnGCbDOcIz8HAuDIAAqtg0BkNwoxpFAmBgJY+ROOgABG-DAAgtzAFAaQgHA7zIBhoAAOZ+HhhHEcgsEUVRfRgFA9Hcs0EgSDOAp0RAYBIShwT5IqHhYt4YlQH4zAgOYAC06DIVAzAEiQEz5IpKlqdAzDDIJfwwJYAJgAAchxUz5OgTByVJyJ4LRIAMSwSnKZRpSaRWWjIMAMCvOgZIwGR7EDAAZJFGRkmxYDeRA3IqGARhWpk2T5AABgAJKQIVheRCUcWIyB5SF8WJWIWXDFQgXBaF4XFaUyUiWlTKZQVTWJbVAVBXZcVwc1SVEm1UDpcyA2VRxvUpe1Ol6V5HFGbY6HpHRKgibZiUnFxPEVllFr8Pw5hlaQVVZU2JnpAgZrmOYADCd2ncEgHAfkwmiepkkVGSYEQuZcBWTNZKhh9m1gBUTYAPTQ8ga3w89T33eul7DrmrnuQARJ5BlQFjUY4ypiVY4k12HG5oAoK9G4fSJck-TDcMI5adFU6jQE1iOcl+ETqnqaT5MIHAxLBKzVN-W+ANQBZ1ktUz8OzvDIsc8BI6Y7zuMC4Tnkk4kCPC-h93IVMwvkmDG0QCJUPkLDisCobxtlK4G7q3tbma-p2vRHzet2EAA)

Comment: you are a hero, thank you so much for this detailed answer. You also taught me a convention of typescript that I didn't have ingrained! Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: You mentioned sythesizing types, which is really what I was asking about - but I'm more than happy with this answer - do you know of any further resources on type synthesis you'd recommend? Or any resources in general you recommend? I find the TS docs to be pretty basic.

Comment: "You mentioned sythesizing types, which is really what I was asking about" I'm not sure I understand... you could, if you want, remove the `RailRoaded` interface definition and the arrow function return type annotation (`: RailRoaded<A, E>`) on the definition of `railRoad()` and the resulting code would work the same, except that the compiler would have a pretty bad time, and when you ask the compiler what the type `railRoad(getUser())` is you'll get a horrendous looking mess.  The introduction of `RailRoaded` just makes everything nicer all around. Am I missing something?

Comment: Recommended resources: I'm not really sure.  I spent a lot of time reading the TS Handbook as well as the [release notes](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html) and the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues).  Oh, and reading SO answers.  No one-stop shop for TS documentation that I know of, I'm afraid.